# Protect uploaded files and provide access only authorized users

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Multer to upload some files and I am wondering what would be the recommended way to protect access to those files after upload.

I have 2 types of users; admin and regular user. Users are only able to upload photos and only admin can access url of the photo.

My folder structure for uploaded files: `./public/uploads/teacher/`

This is my code:

**server.js**

```
// This is auth middleware which checks if access token is valid to access API
app.all('/api/*', [require('./validateReq')]);

app.use('/', require('./routes'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var teacher = require('./teachers.js');

router.post('/upload', teacher.uploadAvatar);
```

**routes/teachers.js**

```
var multer      = require('multer');
var upload      = multer({ dest: 'uploads/teacher/' }).single('avatar');

uploadAvatar: function(req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.file);

        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
}
```

If user uploads a file `john_doe.png`, how can I limit access to the following Url only to teacher/admin so it's not public: `localhost:8000/uploads/teacher/john_doe.png`. What would be the best practice in situations like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is no different than adding an authentication process before returning resources. There are various ways to go about it. For instance, in the most basic of levels, you can use the [basic authentication header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). You can also use cookies (specifically, httpOnly cookies) for passing the authorization cookies and so forth.

Seeing that you already have a middleware for something similar, you can use it to check whether the user has admin privileges before authorizing them to view the resource.